# Kafka Stream KeyValue state Store (KTable)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a requirement that irrespective of time ,  whenever message comes to  kafka topic  ,i need  aggregate all those messages based on the key.

Below logic i have written to achieve this which is working fine.

```
 KStream<String, Sample> sampleKStream =
            builder.stream("inprocess-topic");


 final Materialized<String, Sample, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> sampleStore =
            Materialized.<String, Sample, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("changelog-topic").withLoggingEnabled(changeLogConfigs)
                    .withCachingDisabled();

   KGroupedStream<String,Sample> kgroup = sampleKStream.groupByKey();

   kgroup.
           aggregate(()-> new Sample(null, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", new ArrayList<>()),
           (key , value , aggregator) -> Aggregator.merge(key , value , aggregator),sampleStore )
           .toStream()
           .map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(key, value))
           .selectKey((key, value) -> value.getName())
           .peek(Demo::logOut)
           .filter((k,v) -> v!=null && isComplete(v))
           .to("output-topic");
```

Can any one help -  is there any situation to miss latest aggregated message from KeyValue Store (KTable) except tombstone message  ?  and

will KTable data removed , if we delete state directories from respective path(state.dir) ?

Answer (score 0):

By theory fault-tolerant state stores are backed by a compacted changelog topic and if you are deleting your state store, the application’s state can be fully restored from its changelog topic and you will be not missing any aggregated data.

You can use bin/kafka-streams-application-reset to clean up application in a efficient way too.

For your reference:

https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/

http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#application-reset-tool